# How to declare variable "as" for component's template

Tags: angular, functional-programming, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a question about best practise in Angular. I use ngrx library in my Angular4 app, so I have a normalized state tree in this way:

```
"objects": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1",
      "type": "object",
      "parentId": null
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name2",
      "type": "object",
      "parentId": 1
    }
  },
"selectedId": 2
```

so if I want use selected object in my component template I have to write complicated structure, like:

```
<div *ngIf="(objects$ | async)[(selectedId$ | async)] as selectedObject">
    {{ selectedObject?.name }}
</div>
```

and it looks like fine. It looks worse when I try to refer to parent of selected object. Structure is completely unreadable:

```
<div *ngIf="(objects$ | async)[(objects$ | async)[(selectedId$ | async)].parentId] as parentOfSelectedObject">
    {{ parentOfSelectedObject?.name }}
</div>
```

I tried to remedy this by divisioning into smaller parts:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(objects$ | async)[(selectedId$ | async)] as selectedObject">
    <div *ngIf="(objects$ | async)[selectedObject.parentId] as parentOfSelectedObject">
        {{ parentOfSelectedObject.name }}
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

but I still belive that there is a best way to declare variable for whole component's template. Is it? Something like that:

```
<declare-tag *declare="(objects$ | async)[(selectedId$ | async)] as selectedObject" />
<declare-tag *declare="(objects$ | async)[selectedObject.parentId] as parentOfSelectedObject" />

<div *ngIf="parentOfSelectedObject">
    {{ parentOfSelectedObject.name }}
</div>
```

Which way do you use Observable in component's html? Or maybe I dont understand how to correctly use a state tree in my components? Please, I'm waiting for answers.

Comment: You have a right. I edited my post, because ngrx is not a redux.